# Navigate and copy command line output with keyboard only

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Is there a way to jump from the command line input and navigate through the output, eventually copying parts of it text to the clipboard?

I find myself oftentimes in the situation where:

- the output is too long and goes out of view. In this case I want to scroll up without taking my hands off the keyboard
- there is some piece of text I want to use in a new command. In this case I want to navigate to this piece of text and copy it (similar to vim's visual mode). Again without leaving the keyboard.

I am using iTerm2 on a Mac.

Comment: https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-copymode.html

Answer (score 0):

You can stil use `vim` with help of [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution).

If we have `my_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "first
second
third"
```

Running

```
vim <(./my_script.sh)
```

You will be able to scroll and copy content of `my_script` output like it was text file.